# Wrap text to a tag

Tags: ckeditor

I add a button to CKEditor. I want to wrap the selected text in the tag `h2`. If no text, the button is not working properly. I use the following code.

```
var selected_text = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
var newElement = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('h2');
newElement.setAttributes({style: ''});
newElement.setText(selected_text);
editor.insertElement(newElement);
```

But the tag is added `h2`even if text is not selected. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you can not just check the length before making any changes?

```
var selected_text = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
if(selected_text.length > 0)
{
    var newElement = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('h2');
    newElement.setAttributes({style: ''});
    newElement.setText(selected_text);
    editor.insertElement(newElement);
}
```